# FileSystemWatcher and System Out of Memory Exception

Tags: c#, wpf

A little context

> There is a wpf based application which i left opened for 2-3 days without performing any activity throws out of memory exception , this is very Weird situation and does not happen all of the time. During this ideal activity , my application does nt perform any activity but just a file system watcher contineously watching a shared location , so i thought that would be a problem but i am not sure. Any suggestion is always welcomed.

Comment: Hard to find a memory leak without seeing the code.

Comment: :( , unfortunately , i am not on my office network!

Comment: Can you also provide a stack trace?

Comment: i know , its hard to find and it can be any area of the application but my question can filesystemwatcher produce out of memory exception if it is just watching a shard location and if the application is left opened for 2-3 days or some other time frame

Comment: i will try to post some stack trace but it will take some time , may be after 7-8 hrs

Answer (score 1):

Are you adding something to a list\collection when a FileSystemWatcher event happens? You could be doing this directly, or more possibly indirectly if it is non-obvious.

This could eventually lead to OOM and would be dependant on how many events there had been, so the time taken to reach OOM could be highly variable.

FileSystemWatcher on its own will not lead OOM. It maintains an [internal buffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.internalbuffersize.aspx), but it will overwrite the buffer if file system event data is not taken via FSW events quickly enough.

So no, the FileSystemWatcher will not lead to OOM on its own - the internal buffer mechanism removes this possibility by design.

Comment: no just watching for changes and if the chages are there than write to the file and changes ar very rarely to the location which FSW watching

Comment: @Saurabh I have updated my question is response to your question comments. FSW will not OOM on its own, it is designed to overwrite its internal buffer - this is a design feature to prevent it from consuming too much memory.

Comment: @Saurabh Maybe I'm not understanding your comment, but are you writing to the file you are monitoring? This sounds like the potential for a feedback loop. Also, you may be getting more changes than you think you are. Add some logging to bottom this out.

Answer (score 1):

`windbg` (the debugger from Debugger Tools for Windows, included in the Windows SDK. itself included with VS these days) includes a command to dump statistics on the managed heap. Including what kind of types are allocated. This should help identify what objects are not being collected (probably via some reference that should be been cleared).

This should get you started: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2005/11/25/496973.aspx